# WireShark Ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu

Дано Wireshark под Ubuntu 11.04. Необходимо настроить фильтр по аналогии с HTTP Analyzer под Windows, т.е. необходимо прослушивать трафик с конкретной программы (мб процесса). Возможно, я не в том направлении рассуждаю, но конечный результат мне нужен один - возможность прослушивать http трафик с firefox. Просто отфильтровать по http не вариант, т.к. помимо мозилы есть куча других процессов, которые генерируют такой трафик.

Answer (score 4):

В этом случае возможно wireshark слишком мощный инструмент, а Вам вполне хватит [LiveHttp](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) и плюс классика жанра - [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search). Эти два инструмента покроют 90% задач. А вот когда найдется страница, которая творит непонятно что, вот тогда нужно уже запускать wireshark и отфильтровывать данные ручками.

**UPD:**
Ещё один вариант. Нужно использовать свою http проксю. А браузер настраивается на работу с этой проксей. Посмотрите на [OWASP WebScarab Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_Project) и [bulp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)

Comment: Ну, проблема как раз в том, что страничка сама закрывается и через firebug не получается увидеть запросы, а кнопочка не очищать не помогает.